# Can the supreme court set regulations for how lower courts act in an area where they are at discretion to make decisions ? (India)

Tags: india, indian-constitutional-law

For example if there is an area in which the courts can act in their own discretion like chosing how much compensation can be awarded to a party in a civil lawsuit within the limits of the maximum amount.

Can the supreme court make regulations to those courts on how to apply such laws ?

> https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Constitution_of_India/Part_V

See the chapter "union Judiciary" would any of the provisions of the constitution allow this directly or indirectly ?

https://www.legalserviceindia.com/legal/article-2898-section-482-crpc-quashing-of-fir-guidelines-set-out-by-the-hon-ble-supreme-court-of-india.html
(an example of what I'm talking about)
CrPC 482 states [[nothing in this code shall affect or limit the inherent power of the high court to pass such order as may be neccesarry to secure the ends of justice]] and the supreme court set guidelines for the use of this.

Maybe I'm misreading this but are these binding or non binding
guidelines ?

Comment: Article 141 says that the law declared by the supreme court is binding on all courts but it doesn't say that lower courts are subbordinate to supreme courts in the same way article 227 provides for supervience of the high court over the lower courts. but perhaps supreme courts can Interpret a law in a way to set guidelines ? I don't know perhaps someone else has the answer to that

Comment: can such  interpretations be challenged by lower courts ? @OldAccount2005

Comment: "Guidelines" itself indicates that they are to be used as reference to decision making by the High Court and other courts subordinate to the Supreme Court while making decisions. Can't find a citation for that, so I thought I'll help with what I know in the comments.